# PHP8: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given

Tags: php

I am using the following code, which has been working previously, but after upgrading to PHP8 I get the error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given
```

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        
$content_table = explode("</p>", $content);

$content_table[3] .= $spot1;
$content_table[6] .= $spot2;
$content_table[9] .= $spot3;
$content_table[12] .= $spot4;
$content_table[15] .= $spot5;

$content2 = implode($content_table, "</p>");
        
echo $content2;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough in the end, just had to reverse the implode statement:

```
$content2 = implode("</p>", $content_table);
```

Comment: It's completely fine to answer your own question. However, since the manual specifically states how to use the function, and your issue was essentially a typo, which we usually close instead of answering.

Comment: @M.Eriksson PHP supported the signature `implode(array $array, string $separator): string` as well until it was deprecated in PHP 7.4, and now actually removed with 8.0. So we might as well consider this "outdated code" issue, instead of a typo.